# Htaccess — отдать другую страницу при прямом заходе. Как?

Tags: .htaccess

Вот такой вопрос, уважаемые специалисты. Осуществляется прямой заход на конкретную страницу с разных IP ботами. Как отображать другую страницу для них, т.е. тем, у кого нет реферера?

Вот есть такой код, он выводит другую страницу, но как ввести проверку, чтобы это осуществлялось только при отсутствии реферера?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^material\.html$ statya.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Что если обычный пользователь отключит в своём браузере отправку рефереров?

Comment: Ему будет показываться точная копия страницы, но без счётчика Яндекс Метрика.

Answer (score 1):

Если верить [документации](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) на **mod_rewrite**, есть директива [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond), которая должна быть записана строго перед `RewriteRule`.

Она действует на правило, описанное в `RewriteRule` и позволяет проверять значения в том числе и серверных переменных, а именно `HTTP_REFERER`.

Должно быть что-то вроде этого, но мне негде проверить:

```
RewriteCode %{HTTP_REFERER} =""
RewriteRule ^material\.html$ statya.html
```